# Make parent padding cut off child element

Tags: css, html

I have a square parent container that has a 2% padding on all 4 sides. I have a smaller rectangle that spills over the bottom. I am setting the height of the shape relative to it's parent container. I know I can use `overflow:hidden` but that simply contains the child element, it doesn't make the child respect the parent's padding.

```css
.parent {
   border-radius: 15px;
   background: #cccac9;
   position: absolute; 
   top: 50%; 
   left: 50%; 
   height: 30%; 
   width: 60%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   padding: 2%; 
   overflow:hidden;
}
 
.child {
  background: #1c1c1c; 
  position: relative; 
  height: 30%;   
  color: White; 
  text-align: center; 
  padding-top: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child'></div>
</div>
```

[image: Item I'm working with.]

The grey background is the parent, the black box in the bottom is it's child. The bottom black box is bleeding over the grey parent container's padding.

Comment: I don't understand the question. What are the elements X% height *of*?

Comment: I will update the question to make it clearer, sorry.

Comment: The example can be greatly simplified: https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/ctmqrhhy/ - your other CSS may be the reason - so it's good to start with the most basic set of rues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your child up into a container of its own, then set the `overflow: hidden` on that container. I would also set its height to 100%.

```css
.parent {
   border-radius: 15px;
   background: #cccac9;
   position: absolute; 
   top: 50%; 
   left: 50%; 
   height: 30%; 
   width: 60%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   padding: 2%; 
}
.child-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}
.child {
  background: #1c1c1c;   
  color: White; 
  text-align: center; 
  padding-top: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child-container'>
    <div class="child">
      <p>This is my text</p>
      <p>This is my text</p>
      <p>This is my text</p>
      <p>This is my text</p>
      <p>This is my text</p>
      <p>This is my text</p>
      <p>This is my text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: With this code, the behavior seems to be that the black box fits with anything I put inside of such as text. If I put in enough text, it still goes over so the `overflow:hidden` in the wrapper doesn't seem to affect it.

Comment: Do you have your full code to show? Under what browser? The above code seems to work fine for me.

Comment: I'm using Chrome.